# java date problem in parsing

Tags: java, date

I am parsing a date, where I am passing `2011-02-10 00:00:00:0`, and I am getting `2011-01-10` as the result. Is this wrong? Please help.

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
 today = df.parse(datecollection);
```

Comment: what does datecollection contains, and is "parasing", "parsing"?

Comment: @robobooga fixed format/grammar

Answer (score 3):

The pattern for month is MM: yyyy-MM-dd. You should read the API [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

try using `MM` instead of `mm` should work

refer http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
 M  Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
 m  Minute in hour  Number  30
```

an example

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS"   2001-07-04 12:08:56:235
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using MM not mm. MM is for month, mm is for minute

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `mm` with `MM`. Please take a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) page.

```
try
   {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
            System.out.println(df.parse("2011-02-10 00:00:00:0"));
   }
   catch (Exception e){}
```

Prints:

> Thu Feb 10 00:00:00 CET 2011