# Error converting Date from one format to another format

Tags: java, date

Having trouble in the following code. The output is `dateStr: 11-Jan-11`. Can anyone tell me why the date is modified?

```
String dateStr="";
String actionCompletionDueDate = "16/11/2011";
DateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
DateFormat destDf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");              
if(actionCompletionDueDate != null && !actionCompletionDueDate.equals("")) {
  // parse the date string into Date object
  System.out.println("actionCompletionDueDate: " + actionCompletionDueDate);
  Date actionCompletionDate = srcDf.parse(actionCompletionDueDate);
  dateStr = destDf.format(actionCompletionDate);
  System.out.println("dateStr: " + dateStr);
}
```

Comment: first of all srcDf has month first, your string has day first

Comment: `mm` is for minutes and `MM` or `MMM` are for months. See documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [java date problem in parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966652/java-date-problem-in-parsing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
DateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

to

```
DateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

OR pass a correct string (which respects your format) to your code

```
String actionCompletionDueDate = "11/16/2011";
```

and correct the format to `DateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");`

`mm` is for minutes and `MM` is for months

Comment: I don't think that this "OR" code works, since he would still use the wrong format `mm`.

Comment: @Tom you are right, didn't notice the lowercase 'mm' (edited answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
String actionCompletionDueDate = "16/11/2011";
```

Should be

```
String actionCompletionDueDate = "11/16/2011";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
DateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

to

```
DateFormat srcDf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

small `mm` here corresponds to **minute**.

But if you print source date using,

```
System.out.println(actionCompletionDate.toString());
```

Output is :

```
Sun Jan 16 00:11:00 IST 2011
```

See, **11 minute** in time.

And change source date too, to `11/16/2011`.